# React Native Facebook Login with email access permission error

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm now trying to build a Facebook login view. I installed SDK following the guideline and ended up being able to login to Facebook. However, after logged in, I can't extract email from the callback data although I commanded 'permissions' with email in React Native. The below is a section of Facebook login function.

I was able to access to 'token, token expiration, userID', not to email, profile etc.

```
var {FBLogin, FBLoginManager} = require('react-native-facebook-login');

...
      <FBLogin style={{ marginBottom: 10, }}

      ref={(fbLogin) => { this.fbLogin = fbLogin }}

      permissions={["email","user_friends","public_profile"]}

      loginBehavior={FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native}

      onLogin={function(data){
        console.log("Logged in!");
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
      }.bind(this)}
      onLogout={function(){
        console.log("Logged out.");
        this.setState({ user : null });
      }.bind(this)}
      onLoginFound={function(data){
        console.log("Existing login found.");
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ user : data.credentials });

        console.log(this.state.user.userId);
        console.log(this.state.user.permissions);

        this.props.navigator.push({
          title: 'Results',
          component: Main
        });  
        //

      }.bind(this)}
      onLoginNotFound={function(){
        console.log("No user logged in.");
        this.setState({ user : null });

      }.bind(this)}
      onError={function(data){
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(data);
      }}
      onCancel={function(){
        console.log("User cancelled.");
      }}
      onPermissionsMissing={function(data){
        console.log("Check permissions!");
        console.log(data);
      }} />
```

Please share any thoughts with me. 
Best

Answer (score 1):

Use readPermissions (or publishPermissions) to specify additional permissions such as 'email'.

```
<LoginButton
      readPermissions={["public_profile","email"]}
      publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
      onLoginFinished={...}
      onLogoutFinished={...}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the `accessToken` from the initial call you need to make an additional call using the `accessToken` to get the email / additional information.

Here is a partial example:

```
<LoginButton
      style={[styles.loginButton, styles.loginButtonFB]}
      publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
      onLoginFinished={
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            alert("login has error: " + result.error);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            alert("login is cancelled.");
          } else {
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
              (data) => {
                this.setState({
                  loading: true,
                })
                // HERE IS WHAT YOU NEED
                fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${data.accessToken.toString()}`)
                  .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((res) => {
                    var socialOptions = {
                      email: res.email,
                      firstName: res.first_name,
                      lastName: res.last_name,
                      token: data.accessToken.toString(),
                      uid: data.userID,
                      loginType: 'facebook',
                    }
                    // ignore this--custom api call sending the data to my own api
                    api.socialRegister(socialOptions)
                      .then((response) => {
                        // working
                        this.handleResponse(response);

                      })
                      .catch((error) => console.log('error', error))
                  })
                  .catch((err) => console.log('error occurred', err.message));

              }) // end getCurrentAccessToken

            }
          }
        }

       onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout")}/>
```

That should be what you need. Gl.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for advice. I followed your instruction! And it seems "res" after fetched has only two elements ( Id, and name ). How can I invoke the user to share email, other data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add each permission into readPermission array. Like

> readPermissions={['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday', ]}

Check AccessToken and Result by [this url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cbirthday%2Cemail&version=v2.11)

Answer (score 0):

I figure out by using the following api we can get the email. After we login to facebook, we can do:

https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/176#issuecomment-256153301

```
    var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/' + 
    data.credentials.userId +
    '?fields=name,email&access_token=' + data.credentials.token;
    fetch(api)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then( (responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData.email)
    })
    .done();
```